# Pygame background mask collision not working

Tags: python, pygame

UPDATE - I modified the code to display the car mask and it turns out the mask is in the wrong place (top left corner) and doesn't move...still stuck though.

Simply trying to detect whether or not the car goes off the track, so far I've tried to implement mask collision detection however it doesn't seem to be working as intended. I've tried copying the methods from https://github.com/illume/pixel_perfect_collision/blob/master/balloon.py however even that doesn't work.

Here is the simplified code (full code below):

```
#make masks
car_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(car_image, 50)
back_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(background_image, 50)

#make background rect
back_rect = background_image.get_rect()

#-=-=-=--==-=#
##MAIN LOGIC##
#-=-=-=-=-=-=#

#Get the car rect
rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(car_image, car.angle)
car_rect = rotated.get_rect()

#Calculate offset
offset_x = car_rect[0] - back_rect[0]
offset_y = car_rect[1] - back_rect[1]

#Check for overlap
overlap = back_mask.overlap(car_mask, (offset_x, offset_y))

#Draw everything
self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
self.screen.blit(background_image, (0,0))
self.screen.blit(rotated, car.position * 32 - (car_rect.width / 2, car_rect.height / 2))

#Confirm overlap
if overlap:
    print("collision")
```

Here is the full code:

```
import os
import pygame
from math import tan, radians, degrees, copysign
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Car:
    def __init__(self, x, y, angle=0.0):
        #initialize
        self.position = Vector2(x, y)
        self.velocity = Vector2(0.0, 0.0)
        self.angle = angle
        self.acceleration = 0.0
        self.steering = 0.0

    def update(self, dt):
        #update car variables
        self.velocity = Vector2(self.acceleration, 0)
        angular_velocity = self.steering * dt * self.velocity.x
        self.position += self.velocity.rotate(-self.angle) * dt
        self.angle += degrees(angular_velocity) * dt

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        #initialize
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Car tutorial")
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.ticks = 60
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        #get images
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        image_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "car.png")
        car_image = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert_alpha()
        image_path2 = os.path.join(current_dir, "racetrackv1.png")
        background_image = pygame.image.load(image_path2).convert_alpha()

        #make car
        car = Car(17, 5)

        #make masks
        car_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(car_image, 50)
        back_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(background_image, 50)

        #make background rect
        back_rect = background_image.get_rect()

        while not self.exit:
            dt = self.clock.get_time() / 1000

            #Check for exit
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.exit = True

            #Get user input
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            #Acceleration logic
            if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
                car.acceleration += 1 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                car.acceleration -= 1 * dt
            else:
                car.acceleration *= 0.99

            #Steering logic
            if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                car.steering -= 30 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                car.steering += 30 * dt
            else:
                car.steering = 0

            #Update the car
            car.update(dt)

            #Get the car rect
            rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(car_image, car.angle)
            car_rect = rotated.get_rect()

            #Calculate offset
            offset_x = car_rect[0] - back_rect[0]
            offset_y = car_rect[1] - back_rect[1]

            #Check for overlap
            overlap = back_mask.overlap(car_mask, (offset_x, offset_y))

            #Draw everything
            self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
            self.screen.blit(background_image, (0,0))
            self.screen.blit(rotated, car.position * 32 - (car_rect.width / 2, car_rect.height / 2))

            #Confirm overlap
            if overlap:
                print("collision")

            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(self.ticks)

        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never move the `car_rect` so it stays at the default position (0, 0) the whole time and since it's used to calculate the offset of the masks, the collision detection won't work. The rect's position has to be updated every time the car moves. I've rearranged your code a little bit and put the car's rect, mask and image into the `Car` class where they belong.

```
import os
import pygame
from math import tan, radians, degrees, copysign
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Car:
    def __init__(self, x, y, car_image, angle=0.0):
        #initialize
        self.orig_image = car_image
        self.image = car_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.position = Vector2(x, y)
        self.velocity = Vector2(0.0, 0.0)
        self.angle = angle
        self.acceleration = 0.0
        self.steering = 0.0
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image, 50)

    def update(self, dt):
        #update car variables
        self.velocity = Vector2(self.acceleration, 0)
        angular_velocity = self.steering * dt * self.velocity.x
        self.position += self.velocity.rotate(-self.angle) * dt
        self.rect.center = self.position  # Update the rect each frame.
        self.angle += degrees(angular_velocity) * dt
        # Rotate the orig image, rect and mask.
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.orig_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image, 50)

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        #initialize
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Car tutorial")
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.ticks = 60
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        #get images
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        image_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "car.png")
        car_image = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert_alpha()
        image_path2 = os.path.join(current_dir, "racetrackv1.png")
        background_image = pygame.image.load(image_path2).convert_alpha()

        #make car
        car = Car(17, 5, car_image)  # Pass the image.

        #make masks
        back_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(background_image, 50)
        #make background rect
        back_rect = background_image.get_rect()

        while not self.exit:
            dt = self.clock.get_time() / 1000

            #Check for exit
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.exit = True

            #Get user input
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            #Acceleration logic
            if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
                car.acceleration += 100 * dt
                print(car.acceleration)
            elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                car.acceleration -= 1 * dt
            else:
                car.acceleration *= 0.99

            #Steering logic
            if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                car.steering -= 30 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                car.steering += 30 * dt
            else:
                car.steering = 0

            #Update the car
            car.update(dt)

            #Calculate offset
            offset_x = car.rect[0] - back_rect[0]
            offset_y = car.rect[1] - back_rect[1]

            #Check for overlap
            overlap = back_mask.overlap(car.mask, (offset_x, offset_y))

            #Draw everything
            self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
            self.screen.blit(background_image, (0,0))
            # The old blit position makes no sense to me.
            # self.screen.blit(rotated, car.position * 32 - (car_rect.width / 2, car_rect.height / 2))
            # Just blit the car image at the car rect (top left) coords now.
            self.screen.blit(car.image, car.rect)
            # Make the mask visible to debug it.
            for point in car.mask.outline(8):
                pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 0, 0), (point+Vector2(car.rect.topleft), (2, 2)))

            #Confirm overlap
            if overlap:
                print("collision", car.position)

            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(self.ticks)

        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Also, if you turn your car and the background into [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) and put them into sprite groups, you can use [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) and `pygame.sprite.collide_mask` as the callback function for the collision detection.

Comment: Your solution works like a charm! I had a feeling it was due to the rect not updating but had no idea how to adapt the code, anyways thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome! It helps to print or draw the involved rects and masks if something goes wrong with the collision detection.